# GPUs and google container engine

Tags: gpu, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes supports GPUs as an experimental feature. Does it work in google container engine? Do I need to have some special configuration to enable it? I want to be able to run machine learning workloads, but want to use Python 3 which isn't available in CloudML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPUs on Google Container Engine are now available in Alpha.  [Sign up form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1JNnoUe1_3xZvAogAi16DwH6AjF2eu08ggED24OGO7Xc/viewform?edit_requested=true).

Beware that [alpha cluster limitations](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters) apply: they cannot be upgraded, and they will be auto-deleted in 30 days.

*Disclaimer*: I work at GCP.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not supported out of the box. When creating a regular instance in Google Compute Engine (GCE) you are able to select GPU specs for your machine. On the other side, when creating a cluster, these options are not available. I imagine that this will be available sooner or later, but not at the moment.

As an alternative, you can create several GCE instances and build a cluster using tools like kubeadm or following guides like Kubernetes the hard way: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

Comment: Hey, just a nitpick. Specially people not very familiar with google cloud technologies might interpret GCE as "google container engine" (which seems like a fair assumption at first glance), which would make your answer confusing. If you can, please make it explicit that GCE means "compute" and not "container"

Comment: I think the new convention is GKE (Google Kontainer Engine) :)

Comment: In this case I mean GCE, not GKE. GPUs are available in GCE but not GKE.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it, but as long as GPU vm are just machine types I would say that doing these two steps should make it feasible:

UPDATE: Main site for Custom Machine Types: https://cloud.google.com/custom-machine-types/

1- Create a GPU Custom Machine Type: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/

> You can add GPUs to any non-shared-core predefined machine type or custom machine type that you are able to create in a zone

2- When creating nodes, chose your custom machine type in your cluster or node pool: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations

> --machine-type: The Google Compute Engine machine type (e.g. n1-standard-1) to use for instances in this container cluster. If unspecified, the default machine type is n1-standard-1

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

I'm only able to create custom [instance-templates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create) but not [machine-types](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/machine-types/).
Custom machine options are only given when creating a VM instance or template.

When creating a GKE cluster no custom machine type nor node image can be provide. Unfortunately, we can't use instance-templates in GKE. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create

Comment: Theoretically you can according to here: https://cloud.google.com/custom-machine-types/
And then here: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus

Comment: Yes, but you can't use custom templates on GKE.